# SQL network interface error:50

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a user database & Entity Framework model but I get an error

> A network related or instance error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server.

How to resolve it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, it's very clear - either the server name you're using in the connection string **does NOT exist** (fix: use the server name that *does* exist) - or you cannot reach the server (because there's no network route taking you to the server). Typically, it's just a wrong server name - misspelled, forgot to add the **instance** name - something along those lines

Comment: Agree with @marc_s. If is a remote SQL check also the network (TCP, ports, etc)